# Access inputValue in <Option /> component in react-select 2.*

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to highlight (underline or bold) the text that was entered within all my displayed options. This was quite straightforward in react-select 1.* but I fail in 2.*. when trying to access the `inputValue` within the custom  component.

This code snippet illustrates my attempt when `inputValue` would be available as in `props`:

```
import React from 'react'
import match from 'autosuggest-highlight/match/index'
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse/index'

export default props => {
    // Extract matching parts from the inputValue (value typed into text field)
    const matches = match(props.label, props.inputValue)
    const parts = parse(props.label, matches)

    return (
        <div>
            {parts.map((part, index) => {
                return !part.highlight ? (
                        <span>{part.text}</span>
                    ) : (
                        <strong>{part.text}</strong>
                    )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide a picture of the design you want to achieve ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using a custom `Option` component then you could access the `inputValue` from within the `props.selectProps`.

```
const Option = props => {
  console.log('props', props);
  const { innerProps, innerRef, selectProps, data } = props;
  return (
    <div ref={innerRef} {...innerProps}>
      // generate your highlighted Option from data.label here, using
      // selectProps.inputValue
    </div>
  );
};
// ...
<Select {...otherProps} components={{Option}} />
```